# What survey platform (SaaS) will allow me to send out individualised links, with prefilled information like respondents' names?

Tags: survey, saas

I have thousands of people I need to survey. Once they've answered the survey, I need to match their response to information in a database.

They might give their names in a non standard way (eg Robert -> Bob, using their middle name as first name, etc).

This and other data quality issues makes the post-response matching very difficult.

On the other hand, if I can pre-match their response, by giving them a partly prefilled survey that has their name and other information I have about them first, the matching will be much simpler. Moreover they can answer the interesting and important questions, and not get fatigued with name, postcode, and so on.

I understand that any such service won't be free. Could maybe budget £100 a month for it.

Comment: Many of the survey tools allows to add url parameters to the invitation links. This will not prefill forms but you could store a user id with the response (or any other data). You could also do this for example with PollUnit. Read more here: https://pollunit.com/en/posts/162/store-url-parameter-with-survey

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [AskNicely](https://www.asknicely.com/prices) might d the trick.

> It also integrates with many customer workflow options that include Salesforce, Hubspot, Slack, Zendesk, MailChimp and Zapier amongst many others.
>
> With these connections, surveys can target specific customer groups, and their reaction to new products and services can be collected to present real-time to live dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

Every survey software that supports indidivudal invite links will do.
just make list of the person you are sending it to and the correspoidning invite id. Then you dont even need to ask them for that data.

eg. invite123 is sent to bob@mail.com , so you can later take reply for invite123 and match it with the data for bob. I am assuming you have a table with emails and names, otherwhise the prefilling whould be impossible to do.

I recommend limesuvey as it is free software with professional support available.